# type checking in javascript

Tags: javascript, types

How can I check if a variable is currently an integer type?  I've looked for some sort of resource for this and I think the === operator is important, but I'm not sure how to check if a variable is an Integer (or an Array for that matter)

Comment: == checks for value equality, === checks for value and type equality. "1" == 1 would be true, "1" === 1 would be false

Comment: you can consider using a very small library like [Not](https://github.com/calvintwr/you-are-not). Solves all problems.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

A variable will never be an integer type in JavaScript — it doesn't distinguish between different types of Number.

You can test if the variable contains a number, and if that number is an integer.

```
(typeof foo === "number") && Math.floor(foo) === foo
```

If the variable might be a string containing an integer and you want to see if that is the case:

```
foo == parseInt(foo, 10)
```

Comment: you can also use isNaN(foo) http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_NaN.asp instead of typeof

Comment: *"it doesn't distinguish between different types of Number"* That's because there are no different types of Number. *All* numeric values in JS are 64-bit floats.

Comment: @NullUserException — That's what I said.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can use it's $.type() function. Ex. $.type("1") # => "string"

Comment: One could also use constructor equivalence: `foo.constructor === Number`. One could then throw in the Math.floor or parseInt check to verify the Number is actually an int. The benefit of this is you are actually checking a concrete type name, rather than a string, however that may not quite carry the weight it does in a strongly typed language.

Comment: You can also check if a number x is a valid array index, i.e. a 32-bit integer with x === (x|0).  The binary operator casts to a 32-bit int internally, so if casting to an int and then back to a double leaves the value the same, it's a valid 32-bit int.  Anything out of range or the wrong type gets cast to 0.

Comment: Beware, `typeof new Number(foo)` is "object"

Comment: This answer should be updated as it's inconsistent with the ECMAScript 2015 [*Number.isInteger*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-isinteger) function. It should return false for *Infinity*, not true.

Comment: A functional way of type checking

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794158/1948585

Answer (score 21):

These days, ECMAScript 6 (ECMA-262) is "in the house". Use `Number.isInteger(x)` to ask the question you want to ask with respect to the type of x:

```js
js> var x = 3
js> Number.isInteger(x)
true
js> var y = 3.1
js> Number.isInteger(y)
false
```

Answer (score 7):

A number is an integer if its modulo %1 is 0-

```
function isInt(n){
    return (typeof n== 'number' && n%1== 0);
}
```

This is only as good as javascript gets- say +- ten to the 15th.

`isInt(Math.pow(2,50)+.1)` returns `true`, as does
`Math.pow(2,50)+.1 == Math.pow(2,50)`

Answer (score 2):

## A clean approach

You can consider using a very small, dependency-free library like [Issable](https://github.com/calvintwr/issable). Solves all problems:

```js
// at the basic level it supports primitives
let number = 10
let array = []
is(number).number() // returns true
is(array).number() // throws error

// so you need to define your own:
import { define } from 'issable'
// or require syntax
const { define } = require('issable')

define({
    primitives: 'number',
    nameOfTyping: 'integer',
    toPass: function(candidate) {
        // pre-ECMA6
        return candidate.toFixed(0) === candidate.toString()
        // ECMA6
        return Number.isInteger(candidate)
    }
})
is(4.4).custom('integer') // throws error
is(8).custom('integer') // returns true
```

If you make it a habit, your code will be much stronger. Typescript solves part of the problem but doesn't work at runtime, which is also important.

```js
function test (string, boolean) {
    // any of these below will throw errors to protect you
    is(string).string()
    is(boolean).boolean()

    // continue with your code.
}
```

Comment: could you please explain how to check if something is an integer using this technique?

Comment: @sova i have added the example.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're interested in Integer numbers so I won't re answer that but if you ever wanted to check for Floating Point numbers you could do this.

```
function isFloat( x )
{
    return ( typeof x === "number" && Math.abs( x % 1 ) > 0);
}
```

Note: This MAY treat numbers ending in `.0` (or any logically equivalent number of `0`'s) as an INTEGER. It actually needs a floating point precision error to occur to detect the floating point values in that case.

Ex.

```
alert(isFloat(5.2));   //returns true
alert(isFloat(5));     //returns false
alert(isFloat(5.0));   //return could be either true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also have a look on [Runtyper](https://github.com/vitalets/babel-plugin-runtyper) - a tool that performs type checking of operands in `===` (and other operations).
For your example, if you have strict comparison `x === y` and `x = 123, y = "123"`, it will automatically check `typeof x, typeof y` and show warning in console:

> Strict compare of different types: 123 (number) === "123" (string)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 alert(typeof(1) == "number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few utility libraries such as [YourJS](http://yourjs.com) offer functions for determining if something is an array or if something is an integer or a lot of other types as well.  YourJS defines [isInt](http://yourjs.com/snippets/34) by checking if the value is a number and then if it is divisible by 1:

```
function isInt(x) {
  return typeOf(x, 'Number') && x % 1 == 0;
}
```

The above snippet was taken from [this YourJS snippet](http://yourjs.com/snippets/34) and thusly only works because `typeOf` is defined by the library.  You can download a minimalistic version of YourJS which mainly only has type checking functions such as `typeOf()`, `isInt()` and `isArray()`:  http://yourjs.com/snippets/build/34,2