# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var in queue

Tags: javascript, queue

I was implementing queue in JS, but the console keeps siplaying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var. I used some online debugger and it points error in line 21. This is the code:

```
var queue = function (){

var elements = [];
var cur_element = 0;
var del_elem = 0;
return {
    size: function() {
        return cur_element-del_elem;
    },
    empty: function() {
        return cur_element == 0;
    },
    front: function() {
        if(!this.empty()){
            return elements[0];
        }
        return false;
    },
    back: function() {
        if(!this.empty()){
            return elements[cur_element];
        }
        return false;
    },
    push: function(var elem){
        cur_element++;
        elements[cur_element]=elem;
    },
    pop: function() {
        var outcome = elements[del_elem];
        delete elements[del_elem];
        del_elem++;
        return outcome;
    }
    };
};
```

Comment: `push: function(var elem){` <-- remove var from there, you don't need to tell javascript that a parameter is a `var`, differently from other languages function parameters don't need to be identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove var from:

```
push: function(var elem){
```

In fact, in javascript you don't need (and you **mustn't**) to provide the type of a function parameter because it is a statically typed language (see [Set type for function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407622/set-type-for-function-parameters))

Also, to compare with 0, please use `===` instead of `==`, check this for reference:

http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/?utm_content=buffer4f1b9

So, replace:

```
return cur_element == 0;
```

with:

```
return cur_element === 0;
```

(PLEASE NOTE: REPLACING == WITH === WAS NOT MANDATORY BUT HIGHLY RECOMMENDED!)

Correct code below:

```
var queue = function (){

var elements = [];
var cur_element = 0;
var del_elem = 0;
return {
    size: function() {
        return cur_element-del_elem;
    },
    empty: function() {
        return cur_element === 0;
    },
    front: function() {
        if(!this.empty()){
            return elements[0];
        }
        return false;
    },
    back: function() {
        if(!this.empty()){
            return elements[cur_element];
        }
        return false;
    },
    push: function(elem){
        cur_element++;
        elements[cur_element]=elem;
    },
    pop: function() {
        var outcome = elements[del_elem];
        delete elements[del_elem];
        del_elem++;
        return outcome;
    }
    };
};
```

http://jsbin.com/tirevipoba/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

```
push: function(var elem){
```

remove var

Comment: Then you get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"