# How do I typecheck, objects in a parameter, in a typescript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

I am having issues typechecking some parameters in  a function

```
function myfun({carengine,cartransmission})
{

   // Some code here

}
```

I wish to type check it so it is like this
`function myfun({carengine:CarEngine,cartransmission:CarTransmission})`

However this does not work.

How do I typecheck these parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407622/set-type-for-function-parameters

Comment: No I am using typescript, so it should be possible

Answer (score 1):

Define the type for the structured function argument, eg

```js
interface Car {
  carengine: CarEngine,
  cartransmission: CarTransmission
}

function myfun({ carengine, cartransmission }: Car)
{
   // Some code here
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygURAc1CgbwChlkEBPAG1ABNoBnALmRAFcBbAI2iIF8iiENuzQYAKlDgh67YPXrAA9iGTFSAQQCqYgPLIAvMgBEcVmEXs4YYAiMAaEsgCy6gHKb1AGQPHLbOJRGfAKgkLCIKOhQqo4IGEJ4IBDMUdiJEA6kcVBgktKy8kogKeJ5MnIKysFEMKwgCNbKyOzktSAAFARk8bj4dt05ZQWVKrwlUACURGpkyvSKlBAAdJSKOO0ABgAkBNkJ%20EsU1CB0UPS8ZFS00P072blS5YXKvBtT-C1tnbE96cwzWSuJwYzAAbI5eJkBg98hUiuMJI9hkUli53F4%20BMgA)

If you already have a `Car` type and only want to specify certain properties for your `myfun` function, you can use [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

```js
interface Car {
  carengine: CarEngine,
  cartransmission: CarTransmission,
  doors: number
}

function myfun({ carengine, cartransmission }: Pick<Car, "carengine" | "cartransmission">)
{
   // Some code here
}
```

---

You can also define the argument type inline but it can get messy fast

```js
function myfun({ carengine, cartransmission }: { carengine: CarEngine, cartransmission: CarTransmission })
{
   // Some code here
}
```

Comment: @TypeScriptProgrammer1234 If this worked, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @TypeScriptProgrammer1234 please also dont forget to upvote it :)