# typescript: why is a string implicitly having an 'any' type?

Tags: typescript

```ts
const directoryToBeZipped = `${LOCAL_FILE_PATH}/${attachment.Key}`;
const zipFilePath = `${LOCAL_FILE_PATH}/${zippedFileKey}`;
zipTime = await streamZipLocalDirectory(directoryToBeZipped, zipFilePath);
```

and

```ts
/**
 *  Compress a local directory with all contents into a local zip file;
 *  @param {string} directoryToBeZipped path of local directory that is to be compressed
 *  @param {string} zippedFilePath path of the resultant zip file
 *  @returns {Promise<number>} total execution time in seconds
 */
export const streamZipLocalDirectory = async (
  directoryToBeZipped,
  zippedFilePath
) => {
```

I get this error:

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'directoryToBeZipped' implicitly has an 'any' type.
error TS7006: Parameter 'zippedFilePath' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I understand what this means.

My question is, how is it possible to get this error?

I have this

```ts
const zipFilePath = `${A}/${B}`
```

Why is it not a string? why is it implicitly having an 'any' type?

Comment: The error is about the parameters, not your variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set type for function parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407622/set-type-for-function-parameters), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62105704/283366)