# Typescript overloading best practice

Tags: angular, typescript, overloading

Try to understand the best way to overload methods in TypeScript classes and come with extends error while compiling.

There's an abstract class :

```
export abstract class Collection {
  protected _collection: any;

  public hydrate(key: number, item: Object): Collection;
  public hydrate(key: any, item: any): Collection {
    this._collection.set(key, item);
    return this;
  }

  public size(): number {
    return this._collection.size;
  }
}
```

And the concrete class :

```
export class Tours extends Collection {

  public constructor() {
    super();

    this._collection = new Map();
  }

  public hydrate(key: number, item: Tour) {
    this._collection.set(key, item);  
  }
}
```

Compilation failed with an error on the types of the concrete class (number and Tour) that are not assignable to number and Object of the parent method.

As the Tour type is a custom type, don't know how implement correctly this classes scheme...

How to do that ?

Comment: Why not use OR operator: `public hydrate( key: number | any, item: any | Tour }`. Here's the question that solves this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776625/can-i-specify-parameter-type-as-one-of-many-types-instead-of-any-type-in-typescr#32263803

Comment: Might want to use generics for this kind of thing

Answer (score 2):

You need to preserve the original signature as well:

```
public hydrate(key: number, item: Object) : Collection
public hydrate(key: number, item: Tour) : Collection
public hydrate(key: number, item: Tour) {
    return this._collection.set(key, item);
}
```

In your case however I would recommend making `Collection` generic:

```
export abstract class Collection<T> {
    protected _collection: Map<number, T>;

    public hydrate(key: number, item: T): this {
        this._collection.set(key, item);
        return this;
    }
    ...
}

export class Tours extends Collection<Tour> { }
```

Comment: `_collection` should be typed as `Map<number, T>` also

Comment: @Gerrit0 yes, you are right it would be better, edited the answer

Comment: generic sounds great... but new with TypeScript, what is the <T> type ?

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert it is a type parameter. It allows a class to leave a type unspecified, and lets the user of the class specify any class instead of `T` . You can read more here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html