# how to use 'or' operator when dealing with two different types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that takes an argument with two types.

Refer to the typsescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851677/how-to-get-argument-types-from-function-in-typescript) SO question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776625/can-i-specify-parameter-type-as-one-of-many-types-instead-of-any-type-in-typescr) SO question related to TS functions and types.

#### Function

```
  public onKeydown(ev: KeyboardEvent | EventTarget): void {
    if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
      this.sendMessage();
      ev.target.blur();
    } else {
      this.chatService.emitTyping();
    }
    return;
  }
```

#### HTML for the page

```
          <textarea
            autosize
            [minRows]="1"
            [maxRows]="4"
            [(ngModel)]="message"
            placeholder="escribe aqui"
            class="msg-input"
            (keydown)="onKeydown($event)"
            (click)="scrollToBottom()"
          ></textarea>
```

I cannot see that the function `onKeyDown` has two different types. Because the `or` doesn't seem to have the same effect in Angular as the docs of Typescript say. For example, if the 'Enter' key is pressed then `blur()` the keyboard and send the message. Am I going to have to make a separate function just to blur the keyboard?

This is the error I am getting:

> ERROR in src/Components/chat/chat.component.ts(72,12): error TS2339: Property 'keyCode' does not exist on type 'EventTarget | KeyboardEvent'.
>
> [ng]   Property 'keyCode' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
>
> [ng] src/Components/chat/chat.component.ts(74,10): error TS2339: Property 'target' does not exist on type 'EventTarget | KeyboardEvent'.
>
> [ng]   Property 'target' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: Maybe use a generic type on function parameters and cast with `as` later? https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is typescript is confused because what you are doing is not doable on both EventTarget and KeyboardEvent. So you should tell him directly which one is it in the function. Such as:

```
public onKeydown(ev: KeyboardEvent | EventTarget): void {
    if (<KeyboardEvent>ev.keyCode === 13) { // changed line
      this.sendMessage();
      ev.target.blur();
    } else {
      this.chatService.emitTyping();
    }
    return;
  }
```

you could also do

```
if ((ev as KeyboardEvent).keyCode === 13) {
```

note that sometimes Angular still fails to find the property you need even if it exists in the DOM object, you can then concat the types like

```
type KeyboardCustom = KeyboardEvent & { customProp?: string };
```

meaning that it is both interfaces at the same type (but the second one is purely optional, hence, it will not throw errors when lacking). You could go further with Partials.

```
type CustomInterface = KeyboardEvent & Partial<KeyboardInterface>
```

where KeyboardInterface has any kind of structure.

Comment: Wow thank you for the help! However, when trying to do the same for `.target.blur()` I try to do `(ev as EventTarget).target.blur()` but still get the issue `Property 'target' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`

Comment: this is what I was talking about in angular being weird. Then change the `<KeyboardEvent>ev` to `<KeyboardEvent & { target?: string }>ev`

Angular usually has problems with DOM objects for some weird reason I don't know. A quick workaraound for tighter cases is simply adding <any> behind the object. But only do it if you are at the end or know what you are doing, because this throws the whole purpose of typescript out the window.

Comment: I think I am going to have to disable this, because even with that type conversion now I am getting `property 'blur' does not exist on type 'EventTarget & string'`. I changed it to `(ev as KeyboardEvent & { target?: string }).target.blur();` because the Linter was complaining about the syntax you provided earlier. Thank you for your help again! Still new to Typescript and Angular

Comment: this is probably due to misusage. Either do <any> instead of the complex typing. Or be very specific: `EventTarget & { target?: { blur: Function } }`. **you are welcome!** feel free to ask anything though!

Comment: Yea I had to disable the linter and <any> since the linter complains with <any> since we have to be specific.

Comment: but just so you know. It probably happened cuz you copied exactly the target: string part. This made Typescript expect a string from the target property. And strings have no 'blur' method. Hence the error. If target is an object with a blur property it will stop giving errors. It's super hacky though, so stick to whatever you find better