# No need to declare types in parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback, arguments

I noticed while learning javascript that it does not require you to declare types in the parameter of a function like java does. How does the compiler know what type is passed? is there any type checking? Lets say my function handles numbers instead of strings and I pass a string?

Also normally in javascript do you not need to specify in the parameters that you are passing a function? Again how does the compiler know?

```js
function invokeAdd(a,b){
    return a()+b();
}
```

Comment: Javascript does not have types (in that sense).

Comment: you can use typescript or flow if you want type checking. javascript has  type coercion

Comment: This is a valid question imo. Why the downvote though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To target your specific code blocks, kindly take a look at the below code

```
function sumA()
{
  return 2;
}

function sumB()
{
  return 3;
}

function invokeAdd(a,b){
  return a()+b();
}

console.log(invokeAdd(sumA, sumB)); //5
```

The above code will resulted in 5. Let's break them into steps.

When we first invoke the function `invokeAdd`, we passed in 2 variable `sumA` to be first parameter which is `a` and `sumB` as second parameter which is `b`. Now `invokeAdd` becomes something as below:

```
return sumA() + sumB()
```

and hence return 5.

Now let's take another example where we switch the paramter to numbers.

```
console.log(invokeAdd(1, 2));
```

We now invoke the function `invokeAdd` and passing in 2 parameters, 1 and 2 respectively and our `invokeAdd` has turned into below

```
return 1() + 2();
```

Because 1 is not a function and we have a parenthesis `()` beside it, JS engine will throw an error. **() means execute the function**

> TypeError: a is not a function

If you wish to learn more about types in `javascript`, [You-don't-know-JS](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html) is a very good book with detailed explainations

Comment: Here is more functional way of doing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64794158/1948585

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't need to know what type of parameters you are passing.

JS is a "*dynamically typed*" language, which means that it can figure out types as you go.

In the example you gave, passing a non-function type in would result in an error, because the two types are not functions.  (However, JS is perfectly fine doing all kinds of other conversions)

A couple of examples are below:

```js
console.log("hello"+1);
console.log("2"+1);
console.log(15+true);
let a = (x)=>x+3;
console.log(a);
console.log(a(1));
console.log(a+1);
```

If you desire static type checking in JS; [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [Flow](https://flow.org/en/) are alternative languages which transpile into JS.

Comment: Mystery downvoter, care to comment on what I got wrong?

Comment: All four sentences posted are valid explanations but they are more suited as comments rather than an answer.

Comment: The code examples compliments your sentences now. Downvote removed.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not a compiled language; It's an interpreted language. So no static type-checking.

To answer one of your specific questions:

> Lets say my function handles numbers instead of strings and I pass a string?

You can try this out quite easily:

```js
let number = 1;
let string = "STRING";

let addition = number + string;

console.log(addition);
```

Notice that all this does is concatenate the two variables. So 1 + "STRING" is 1STRING (and the result is a string type).

It's also worth noting, that *variables* do not have types but *values* do. In the above code, *addition* could be set to anything. You could set it as a string on one line and then a number on another and no error will be thrown (until you try to do something invalid with a number or a string). If you want to check the value of a variable before performing some action on it, you can do something like `typeof addition === "string"` (for example, to see if the value of the addition variable is a string).