# How can I determine the type of ActiveXObject and object created in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object, activex, activexobject

1)

Say I have the following in JavaScript:

```
var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
var xmlDoc2 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
var xmlDoc3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

typeof xmlDoc;  // returns object
typeof xmlDoc2; // returns object
typeof xmlDoc3; // returns object
```

How do I return the type of ActiveXObject of each one, i.e. `Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0`, `Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0`? I want to observe if xmlDoc's `ActiveXObject` is equal to xmlDoc2's `ActiveXObject`.

2)

```
 // object XMLDocument
 var xmlObj = document.implementation.createDocument ("", "", null); 
 typeof xmlObj; // returns object
```

Same situation as ActiveXObject, except this object is defined as `XMLDocument`. How would I be able to validate that it is `XMLDocument`? Again, `typeof` returns *object*, which is not really helpful here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514602/type-checking-in-javascript

Comment: Have you tried `xmlObj.toString()` method?