# Need 0 to be different than null

Tags: javascript, operators, jsx

Here's my code in this div tag:

```
<div className="lk-btn-group btn-group clear">
            {this.state.invoiceId ? <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left" onClick={() => this.printInvoice()}>{abp.localization.localize('PrintInvoice')}</button> : null}
            {this.state.delivery.delivery && !this.state.invoiceId ? <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left" onClick={() => this.printDeliveryNote()}>{abp.localization.localize('PrintDeliveryNote')}</button> : null}
            {this.state.delivery.delivery == null ? <button className="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" onClick={() => {
             this.markAsDelivered()
            }} disabled={!this.state.beginningPercentage || !this.state.gallonsDelivered}>{this.props.completeDelivery}</button> : <span className="label label-default pull-right"><i className="fa fa-check"></i> {this.props.deliveryComplete}</span>} 
</div>
```

My question is how do I get an input of 0 (zero) to **not** be the same as null? I need the ability for the user to go ahead and put a 0 and have my disabled button **show** rather than be **disabled**. I believe it's happening at the `== null` in the fourth line of the div code above, which appears to me to disable the "btn btn-primary btn-sm pull right"

That's fine if the user hasn't entered anything yet, but I also need the 0 to be treated as any other value entered and not just null or empty if that makes sense. I still need all the other functionality to remain the same.

Comment: 0 is not the same as null in either C# or JavaScript. Not exactly sure what you mean (obviously you know that `==` and `===` are different... just checking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript checking for null vs. undefined and difference between == and ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101948/javascript-checking-for-null-vs-undefined-and-difference-between-and)

Comment: it's in c# (asp.net mvc project) but the actual file is a .jsx file which compiles to a .js file. All I know is that anytime I put a 0 in there, it still disables the button. I have tried === to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found this, I hope it helps you, essentially you can use `typeof` to check the type of `this.state.delivery.delivery`

```
// typeof this.state.delivery.delivery is a number
if (typeof this.state.delivery.delivery === "number")
```

This answer expands on this principle.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4514622/6558939

You could also try `Number.isInteger(typeof this.state.delivery.delivery)` which should return true or false satisfying the ternary operator.

Comment: so... syntax wise, would I substitute this:
`this.state.delivery.delivery == null`
for this:
`(typeof this.state.delivery.delivery === "0")`
?

Comment: Yes that should work. `(typeof this.state.delivery.delivery === "number")` should fail whenever `this.state.delivery.delivery` is NaN apparently `Number.isInteger(this.state.delivery.delivery)` should work too.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong syntax wise. I can't get this to work. Just makes my page blank. Thank you, just the same. I haven't found the solution yet.

Comment: Hmm that's a shame, I updated my answer with the other way you should be able to determine if the number is an integer try replacing `this.state.delivery.delivery == null` with  `Number.isInteger(typeof this.state.delivery.delivery)`

Also I see what you're saying the code you were given is pretty confusing :P that ternary operator is nuts! It's supposed to make things shorter!