# Strict type checking of @Input for component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created [a sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vb4wbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

As you can see, I am passing `ipNumber = '99';` to `HelloComponent`.

but the `@Input` is like

```
@Input() someVal : number;
```

I want to throw error when string is passed in @Input.

The correct input should be

```
ipNumber = 99;
```

and not

```
ipNumber = '99';
```

Comment: Please check this link:
https://blog.rsuter.com/angular-2-typescript-property-decorator-that-converts-input-values-to-the-correct-type/

Comment: use typeof to check type in your ngOninit lifecycle hook of child component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [type checking in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514602/type-checking-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can validate your input using ngOnChanges Lifecycle hook

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        const nameType = typeof changes['name'].currentValue;
        if ( nameType !== 'string' ) {
          console.warn(`You provided ${nameType} where string was expected`);
        }
      }
```

Check this article for more Info:https://medium.com/@abdelelmedny/angular-input-decorators-5d38089070aa

Comment: If the approach of throwing an error is taken, it should be done onChanges. This is important because it ensures that an error is thrown even if the input is changed after the component is first created.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it inside of the `constructor`, it won't work because the life cycle of the angular component hasn't got to this point, so you can put it in the `ngOnInit` or in a function and call it in the `ngOnInit` or any other life cycle that happens after.
Please check the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
     if(typeof this.someVal !== 'number') {
      console.error("This is not a number");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check the type of `@Input` is using **typeof** provided by javascript. It will check the data type provided value is number or not then we can throw the error like below

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() someVal : number;

  constructor(){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.someVal)

    if(typeof this.someVal !== "number" ) {
      throw new Error('Please provide only number');

    }
  }


}
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3r477?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)**